# Why is my Python code returning a TypeError?

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I'm want a function that checks a string with numbers for odd ones. I want it to print out the position of the odd number(s), but line 4 gives 'TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting'. How do i fix this?
Code below:

```
def IQ_test(string):
    numbers = string.split()
    for x in numbers:
        if x % 2 != 0:
            print(numbers.index(x))
IQ_test("1 4 7 5 2")
```

Comment: Youre trying to run modulo on a string. You pass a string to your function, split it into chars and then try and run a maths function on it. You need to convert the chars into numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `int()` to convert the chars into int type:

```
def IQ_test(string):
    numbers = string.split()
    for x in numbers:
        if int(x) % 2 != 0:
            print(numbers.index(x))
            
IQ_test("1 4 7 5 2")
```

Answer (score 0):

use it :

```
def IQ_test(string):
    numbers = string.split(' ')
    for x in numbers:
        if int(x) % 2 != 0:
            print(numbers.index(x))
IQ_test("1 4 7 5 2")
```

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned in this thread, you didn't convert the elements in `numbers` list into `int` type.

But I would like to highlight a possible bug in your logic:

Using `numbers.index(x)` you will find the first occurrence of element `x` in your list so if the same number repeats more than once, you will get always the first index.

If this is not the desired behavior, you can do:

```
for index, x in enumerate(numbers):
     if int(x) % 2 != 0:
         print(index)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fix! This was indeed not the desired behavior